# Leaflet Control Layer shows up properly in one page and won't show up with the same code in other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use a Leaflet layer in my website, so I tested in a page [Working Page](http://weatherion.com/test/test2.html), which worked really fine. So I copied the code into my original website [Not Working Page](http://weatherion.com/test1.html), and tried running it, but the Control layer doesn't seem to be the same like in the test page. Please help me with this, so that I could use it properly like in the working test page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 105 of your `style.css` file you're globally styling all input elements on your page which interferes with Leaflet's layer control. If you remove the width and height rules, it will be ok:

```
input {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  border: none;
  font-family: "Myriad Set Pro";
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

You should consider applying style on selected elements by using element ID's or CSS classes. If you google for "How to apply CSS to HTML" you'll find lots of tutorials like this one below for example. It will spare you from running into stuff like this because you can apply style to only the element(s) you specify.

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/